# Dataframe output from a for-loop

Tags: r

I am trying to populate the output of a for loop into a data frame. The loop is repeating across the columns of a dataset called "data". The output is to be put into a new dataset called "data2". I specified an empty data frame with 4 columns (i.e. ncol=4). However, the output generates only the first two columns. I also get a warning message: "In matrix(value, n, p) : data length [2403] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [2]"

Why does the dataframe called "data2" have 2 columns, when I have specified 4 columns? This is my code:

```
a <- 0
b <- 0 
GM <- 0
GSD <- 0
data2 <- data.frame(ncol=4, nrow=33)
for (i in 1:ncol(data))
{
    if (i==34) {break}
    a[i] <- colnames(data[i])
    b <- data$cycle
    GM[i] <- geoMean(data[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
    GSD[i] <- geoSD(data[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
    data2[i,] <- c(a[i], b, GM[i], GSD[i])  
}
data2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `?data.frame()` help page, you'll see that it does not take arguments `nrow` and `ncol`--those are arguments for the `matrix()` function.

This is how you initialize `data2`, and you can see it starts with 2 columns, one column is named `ncol`, the second column is named `nrow`.

```
data2 <- data.frame(ncol=4, nrow=33)
data2
#   ncol nrow
# 1    4   33
```

Instead you could try `data2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 4, nrow = 33))`, though if you share a small sample of `data` and your expected result there may be more efficient ways than explicit loops to get this job done.

Generally, if you do loop, you want to do as much outside of the loop as possible. This is just guesswork without having sample data, these changes seem like a start at improving your code.

```
a <- colnames(data) 
b <- data$cycle ## this never changes, no need to redefine every iteration
GM <- numeric(ncol(data)) ## better to initialize vectors to the correct length
GSD <- numeric(ncol(data))
data2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 4, nrow = 33))
for (i in 1:ncol(data))
{
    if (i==34) {break}
    GM[i] <- geoMean(data[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
    GSD[i] <- geoSD(data[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
    ## it's weird to assign a row of data.frame at once...
    ## maybe you should keep it as a matrix?
    data2[i,] <- c(a[i], b, GM[i], GSD[i])  
}
data2
```